# Variable of function always returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, return, keytar

**The idea:**

I want to return a variable from a function and then output it using `console.log()`.

**The problem:**

I can't just use `return result` because then nothing is returned.

I don`t really know how else to return the variable.


I have already looked at SO posts [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call), however I probably lack suitable understanding to implement this into my code.

**The current code**

```
function getPassword(username) {
    const password = keytar.getPassword(service, username) // Function from keytar lib
    password.then((result) => {
        console.log(result)         // Prints password
        return result               // Doesn't return anything
    })
}

pw = getPassword("Name")

// Exemplary, will be replaced by display in Div
console.log(pw)                     // Outputs "undefined"
```

Comment: The keytar.getPassword(service, username) call returns a promise. The only way to proceed with the result is to chain in a routine after the promise completes (in a callback). The asynchronous behaviour is in the dna of promises. Unless I didn't understand your question right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getPassword(username) {
    const password = keytar.getPassword(service, username) // Function from keytar lib
    // don't forget to return promise
    return password.then((result) => {
        console.log(result)         // Prints password
        return result               // Doesn't return anything
    })
}

getPassword("Name").then(result => console.log(result))
```